# IsolatedStorageFile giving exception

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

In windows phone 7, I am trying to write to a file and then trying to read from a file, but while reading it is giving the exception below.

```
public static void writeToFile(String videoUrl)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    store.CreateDirectory("MyFolder");
    IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyFolder\\data.txt", FileMode.Append, 
                                            FileAccess.Write, store);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.WriteLine(videoUrl);
}

public static void readFromFile()
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyFolder\\data.txt", FileMode.Open,
                                                 store);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("kkkkkk-----------------" + line); // Write to console.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ESPNGoalsUtil::readFromFile : " + ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at ESPNGoals.Utility.ESPNGoalsUtil.readFromFile()
```

I am writing the file and then reading the file in the same method and not closing the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) on the `StreamWriter` before `writeToFile` returns (or better still wrap the code in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) block).

The same applies to `StreamReader` in `readFromFile`.